# WCF error from "System.ServiceModel.Administration.WbemProvider" in event log

Tags: wcf, configuration

we run a WCF service hosted in IIS7 on Win2k8. We see the following error in the event log.

The WMI provider was not registered.
 WMI Object: System.ServiceModel.Administration.WbemProvider/65126532
 Error:80041003
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 10144

Which WMI provider has not been registered?
What setup procedure was supposed to register it, and failed?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The account under which the service was running had no rights to register the WCF WMI provider. Goto "Computer Management" -> Services and applications. Right-click on the "WMI Control" node and select properties.
Adjust rights of the "ServiceModel" namespace via the "Security" tab.

[image: Computer management tree screenshot]